# Por qué una funcion para cambiar contenido de un DIV se quita automaticamente en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente opción que según el botón que sea pulsado cambiara el nombre de un mismo elemento `<li>`.

*El problema solo lo cambia por un momento y luego se regresa al contenido original*:

```js
function cambiar(opcion) {
     switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>El Evangelio</font></a></li>";
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>Hip Hop</font></a></li>";
            break;
     case 3:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>Breakdance</font></a></li>";
      break;
     case 4:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>Foundation</font></a></li>";
      break;
     case 5:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>La Persona</font></a></li>";
      break;
     case 6:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>El Cuerpo</font></a></li>";
      break;
     case 7:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>La Mente</font></a></li>";
      break;
     case 8:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<li id='titulo'><a href=''><font size='18'>El alma</font></a></li>";
      break;
        default:
    }
    }
```

```html
    <li id="titulo"><a href=""><font size="18">Street Level</font></a></li>
    <a onclick="cambiar(1);" href="">Presentacion</a>
    <a onclick="cambiar(2);" href="">Hip Hop</a>
    <a onclick="cambiar(3);" href="">Breakdance</a>
```

Como puedo hacer que cambie el contenido y se mantenga asi?

Comment: Intenta poner adentro de los `href` `javascript:(void)`

Comment: @Lixus Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza `event.preventDefault()` para evitar el redireccionamiento o refresh que hace el enlace, solo lo agregarías antes del `switch()`

```js
function cambiar(opcion) {
  event.preventDefault();
  switch (opcion) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>El Evangelio</font></a>";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>Hip Hop</font></a>";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>Breakdance</font></a>";
      break;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>Foundation</font></a>";
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>La Persona</font></a>";
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>El Cuerpo</font></a>";
      break;
    case 7:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>La Mente</font></a>";
      break;
    case 8:
      document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = "<a href=''><font size='18'>El alma</font></a>";
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

```html
<li id="titulo">
  <a href="">
    <font size="18">Street Level</font>
  </a>
</li>
<a onclick="cambiar(1);" href="">Presentacion</a>
<a onclick="cambiar(2);" href="">Hip Hop</a>
<a onclick="cambiar(3);" href="">Breakdance</a>
```